# Type 'ParseSource' does not conform to protocol 'InputSource'

Tags: ios, swift, parsing

I was able to get this project updated to the newest versions of the PODs but an older developer wrote this code and im getting the error:

```
Type 'ParseSource' does not conform to protocol 'InputSource'
```

For the life of me i understand something is missing here and i just cant wrap my head around this error exactly.

What the code snippet looks like:

```
public class ParseSource: NSObject, InputSource {
var file: PFFile
var placeholder: UIImage?

/// Initializes a new source with URL and optionally a placeholder
/// - parameter url: a url to be loaded
/// - parameter placeholder: a placeholder used before image is loaded
public init(file: PFFile, placeholder: UIImage? = nil) {
    self.file = file
    self.placeholder = placeholder
    super.init()
}

public func load(to imageView: UIImageView, with callback: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
    self.file.getDataInBackground {(data: Data?, error: Error?) in
        if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            imageView.image = image
            callback(image)
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the InputSource Core File from ImageSlider Framework we are working with:

```
import UIKit

/// A protocol that can be adapted by different Input Source providers
@objc public protocol InputSource {
/**
 Load image from the source to image view.
 - parameter imageView: Image view to load the image into.
 - parameter callback: Callback called after image was set to the image view.
 - parameter image: Image that was set to the image view.
 */
func load(to imageView: UIImageView, with callback: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> Void)

/**
 Cancel image load on the image view
 - parameter imageView: Image view that is loading the image
*/
@objc optional func cancelLoad(on imageView: UIImageView)
}

/// Input Source to load plain UIImage
@objcMembers
open class ImageSource: NSObject, InputSource {
var image: UIImage!

/// Initializes a new Image Source with UIImage
/// - parameter image: Image to be loaded
public init(image: UIImage) {
    self.image = image
}

/// Initializes a new Image Source with an image name from the main bundle
/// - parameter imageString: name of the file in the application's main bundle
public init?(imageString: String) {
    if let image = UIImage(named: imageString) {
        self.image = image
        super.init()
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

public func load(to imageView: UIImageView, with callback: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    imageView.image = image
    callback(image)
}
}
```

What I would like to know is how can i resolve the above error and what exactly causes this so if I run into this error again i know the best way into resolving it.

Comment: The error probably means you haven't written some required functions or setter getter properties defined in protocol `InputSource`. If your XCode does not shows how to add method stubs, simply press Command+K after clean finished close the xcode and run again.

Comment: Can you show the `InputSource` file? So that other can answer your question?

Comment: @CosmosMan I updated it with that, sorry about that.

Comment: @CosmosMan Im still having issues and actually got more errors trying to add the optional Init call...still scratching my head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your signature is slightly off on ParseSource's implementation.  Notice the callback signature on the protocol:

`with callback: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> Void`

Your implementation has a type mismatch and does not take an optional image:

`with callback: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void`

Changing your implementation to match the definition should fix it (reproduced in a Playground).